# How to write a recursive MySQL query for a sequential trace of project management task records

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, project-management, recursive-query

I am attempting to refactor a project management system, and I would like help writing a recursive MySQL query to sequentially trace all the tasks in a project.  I think it will most likely require a stored procedure.

Consider two projects:

Milestone A through milestone F - 10 tasks (see illustration of project chart):

[image: Project A]

Milestone U through milestone W - 6 tasks (see illustration of project chart):

[image: Project U]

Implementing these projects into two MySQL tables - `proj` and `proj_task`, the table `proj` lists all 16 project tasks, while the `proj_task` table describes the relationships of each task listing the parent task in the id_parent field and the child task in the id_child field:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proj` (
  `id` int(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_task_event` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `proj` (`id`, `project_task_event`) VALUES
(1, 'Task A'),
(2, 'Task B'),
(3, 'Task C'),
(4, 'Task D'),
(5, 'Task E'),
(6, 'Task F'),
(7, 'Task G'),
(8, 'Task H'),
(9, 'Task I'),
(10, 'Task J'),
(11, 'Task U'),
(12, 'Task V'),
(13, 'Task W'),
(14, 'Task X'),
(15, 'Task Y'),
(16, 'Task Z');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proj_task` (
  `id` int(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_parent` int(13) NOT NULL,
  `id_child` int(13) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_parent` (`id_parent`,`id_child`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `proj_task` (`id`, `id_parent`, `id_child`) VALUES
(1, 0, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 2, 3),
(4, 2, 4),
(5, 3, 5),
(6, 4, 5),
(7, 5, 6),
(8, 1, 7),
(9, 1, 8),
(10, 7, 9),
(11, 8, 9),
(12, 9, 10),
(13, 10, 6),
(14, 0, 11),
(15, 11, 12),
(16, 12, 13),
(17, 11, 14),
(18, 14, 15),
(19, 15, 13),
(20, 11, 16),
(21, 16, 13);
```

The two tasks A and U have no parent (id_parent = 0) so by definition, they each define a new project:

```
select p.`project_task_event` as 'Projects' from `proj` p, `proj_task` t where p.id = t.`id_child` and t.`id_parent` = 0;
+----------+
| Projects |
+----------+
| Task A   |
| Task U   |
+----------+
```

Can anyone help me write a recursive MySQL query to SELECT each of the project's tasks (example output below), just using the above tables?  The exact output I am looking for is to list the project tasks (`proj`.`project_task_event`) that are child descendants from a given project beginning parent (where `proj_task`.`id_parent` = 0).  The parent can be referenced either by its unique `proj`.`id` or it's unique `proj_task`.`id`.

```
+---------------+
| Project Tasks |
+---------------+
| Task A        |
| Task B        |
| Task C        |
| Task D        |
| Task E        |
| Task F        |
| Task G        |
| Task H        |
| Task I        |
| Task J        |
+---------------+

+---------------+
| Project Tasks |
+---------------+
| Task U        |
| Task V        |
| Task W        |
| Task X        |
| Task Y        |
| Task Z        |
+---------------+
```

At the moment, the system currently has one extra field in the `proj` table, which makes the above SELECT queries trivial, but I want to eliminate this field as all the necessary data appears to be present to do a recursive query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proj` (
  `id` int(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_task_event` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `proj_id` int(13) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `proj_id` (`proj_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `proj` (`id`, `project_task_event`, `proj_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Task A', 1),
(2, 'Task B', 1),
(3, 'Task C', 1),
(4, 'Task D', 1),
(5, 'Task E', 1),
(6, 'Task F', 1),
(7, 'Task G', 1),
(8, 'Task H', 1),
(9, 'Task I', 1),
(10, 'Task J', 1),
(11, 'Task U', 11),
(12, 'Task V', 11),
(13, 'Task W', 11),
(14, 'Task X', 11),
(15, 'Task Y', 11),
(16, 'Task Z', 11);

select `project_task_event` as 'Project Tasks' from `proj` where `proj_id` = 1;
+---------------+
| Project Tasks |
+---------------+
| Task A        |
| Task B        |
| Task C        |
| Task D        |
| Task E        |
| Task F        |
| Task G        |
| Task H        |
| Task I        |
| Task J        |
+---------------+

select `project_task_event` as 'Project Tasks' from `proj` where `proj_id` = 11;
+---------------+
| Project Tasks |
+---------------+
| Task U        |
| Task V        |
| Task W        |
| Task X        |
| Task Y        |
| Task Z        |
+---------------+
```

Comment: what is the exact output you need?

Comment: @reds I updated the post to state "The exact output I am looking for is to list the project tasks (`proj`.`project_task_event`) that are child descendants from a given project beginning parent (where `proj_task`.`id_parent` = 0).  The parent can be referenced either by its unique `proj`.`id` or it's unique `proj_task`.`id`."  Thanks.

Comment: nee to be clear in tables? are we working two tables only?the proj and proj_task table?

Comment: wheres id_parent and id_child came from? i mean where is it value came from

Comment: @reds yes just the two tables only - the proj and proj_task tables. The values in proj_task.id_parent and proj_task.id_child both come from values in proj.id.  So for example looking at the first illustration you can see how Task I is dependent on both Task G and Task H, corresponding to the records `proj_task`.`id` = 10 and `proj_task`.`id`=11.

Comment: you mean all of this is depend on id_parent and id_child?

Comment: I don't think I'm familiar with a model in which both the parent and child of a given entity are stored. Does it have a name?

Comment: Yes @reds it does all depend on id_parent and id_child.

Comment: @Strawberry, I'm not sure if the database model has a name, but in project management they are called PERT Charts (Program evaluation and review technique) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_evaluation_and_review_technique, where any one task can have many children and/or many parents.

Comment: Hm, that only seems to consider parent id (the arrows only point one way)

Comment: Yes @Strawberry, my arrows only point one way also.  But tasks still need a one-to-many relationship - with one task having multiple parents and/or multiple children.  How else might it be implemented?

Comment: I don't think so. A task only needs to take account of its parents (its dependencies), not its children

Comment: I can understand how a task only needs to take account of its parents (its dependencies), not its children, if the `proj`.`proj_id` field is not removed.  I cannot understand how to write a MySQL query to display the sequence of task records in a project once the `proj`.`proj_id` is gone.  Can you solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

```
   select DISTINCT a.id,a.project_task_event,a.proj_id,a.id_parent,a.id_child,b.project_task_event from 
(select a.id,project_task_event,proj_id,id_parent,id_child from 
(select id,project_task_event,proj_id from proj) as a
left JOIN
(select id,id_parent,id_child from proj_task)as b
on a.id = b.id_parent) as a

left JOIN


(select a.id,project_task_event,proj_id,id_parent,id_child from 
(select id,project_task_event,proj_id from proj) as a
left JOIN
(select id,id_parent,id_child from proj_task)as b
on a.id = b.id_parent)as b
on a.id_child = b.id
```

The Result:
[image]

This is the sample given:
[image]

Comment: This result return to the first illustration as follows above.Just want you to check it.

Comment: Well @reds your elegant solution is VERY close, displaying all the tasks from all the projects.  Many thanks.  

As stated, I am looking to refactor it without the `proj`.`proj_id` field.  When I simply remove the `proj`.`proj_id` field from your query, we still get the same correct result, displaying all the tasks from all the projects.

Comment: My example given displays 2 projects, but in production the tables could hold data for many projects.  How would we constrain the query to display just those tasks from say the first project, given `proj`.`id` = 1 for Task A ?

Or alternately constrain the query to display just those tasks from say the second project, given `proj`.`id` = 11 for Task U ?

Comment: it means you need to get all task according to project id?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this for a project of arbitrary complexity with a sinle query. MySQL does not provide recursive queries (see [Oracle's CONNECT BY syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) for how this is implemented elsewhere,).  A partial solution would be to use the [oq graph engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/oqgraph-storage-engine/) for mysql however I find it somewhat limited and difficult to integrate with other datasets in queries.

I suggest that the best solution would be to populate a temporary table using a procedure/function. In pseudo code....

```
 Create temptable (
      Node integer primary key,
      Gen integer);

Set generation=0;

Insert into temptable (node, gen) values (starting_node, generation);

Do
    Insert ignore into temptable (node, gen)
    Select child_id, generation+1
    From  temptable tt
    Inner join proj_tasks pj
       On tt.node=pj.parent_id
    Where tt.gen=generation;

    If 0 rows inserted or generation ≥ max_iterations break;

    Set generation = generation+1;
 Repeat;

 Select * from temptable;
```